# Simplifying the Gaussian log-likelihood function

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, sampling

Starting from the log-likelihood function for a Gaussian,

$$
\mathcal{L}\mathcal{L}
=
- \frac{N}{2} \log{\left(2 \pi\sigma^2\right)}
- \frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^{N}{{\left(x_i - \mu\right)}^2}
\tag{1}
$$

if we assume the population to be well-represented by the sample distribution such that
$
\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}{{\left(x_i - \mu\right)}^2}}{N}
$
, can we simplify the term on the right to $\frac{N}{2}$, resulting in:

$$
\mathcal{L}\mathcal{L}
=
-\frac{N}{2}
\left(\log{\left(2 \pi\sigma^2\right)} + 1 \right)
\tag{2}
$$

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. However, you can set $\hat\mu=\bar x$, and $$\hat \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i (x_i-\hat\mu)^2$$
to get the *profile likelihood*

$$\ell = -\frac{N}{2}\left(\log(2\pi\hat\sigma^2)+1\right)$$

This is useful for comparing different models.  A similar approach is useful in fitting mixed models, where the profile likelihood with $\mu$ and $\sigma$ profiled out still depends on the other variance parameters.

You *can't* write
$$\ell(\sigma^2) = -\frac{N}{2}\left(\log(2\pi\sigma^2)+1\right)$$
because that's only a good approximation if $\sigma^2\approx\hat\sigma^2$; it's *not* a good approximation as $\sigma^2$ varies.